# How to revert the functionality of a lambda/function in python

Tags: python, function, lambda

I am trying to degenerate my data from already manipulated data. It takes five parameters: target, source, target_key, source_key, transformer
**For example:**

```
target = {}
source = {first_name: tom}
target_key = name
source_key = first_name
transformer = lambda value: value.title()
```

So, currently, I set first_name to name. and response becomes {name: Tom}

Now, I am trying to reverse it. If I get {name: Tom}, it should result in {first_name: tom} using same lambda or function. similarly, there are many other keys with different transformers

Is there any way/keyword to reverse the functionality of a lambda or any function.

Thanks,

Comment: Except for enumerating all inputs in "parallel" you cannot reverse a lambda in general no. This is not a limitation of Python, but a fundamental aspect.

Comment: Since `.title()` is not one-to-one it doesn't have an inverse. If all of the original data is in lower case then `.lower()` can of course be used to restore it.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  What function do you pass `target`, `source`, `target_key`, `source_key` and `transformer` to?  It may be possible to figure out a function that can be written as the inverse of this one, or maybe even possible to use this function as its own inverse, by passing different parameters.  Or, maybe zoom out a bit.  Before you end up with `{name: Tom}`, why not save your input, so it's already there?  Then you just need a dictionary or other way to map from your data that had `{name: Tom}` and presumably your `source`.  Voting to close as (very) unclear.

Comment: @JohnColeman: well some people see functions as a predicate where every input maps on one output. In that sense you could have an "inverse" predicate, or produce a function that enumerates over all possible inputs that result in the output, but indeed, that is only valid in theory.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True enough, but OP wants to recover the original input so couldn't use a many-valued inverse. In any event, computable functions don't always have computable inverses, even if you allow for many-valued inverses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** is if *fundamentally* impossible to construct an "inverse" function for a given function.

You cannot derive the "reverse" function from a given function (whether it is a lambda expression) is irrelevant. There are several aspects here:

First of all, it is possible that ***several* inputs map on the same output**. Take for instance the function `lambda x : x.lower()`. In that case both `'foo'` and `'FOO'` map to `'foo'`. So even if you somehow could calculate input that maps on a given output, a question would be: "what input do you pick".

Next say we simply state that *any* input would suffice, one can ask whether it is possible. It still is not since the problem is also **undecidable** in the sense that if you provide as "expected output" a **value that *cannot* be generated by the function**, the hypothetical inverse function cannot know that. One can prove this by using computability theory since it would conflict with the fact that the *emptiness problem E<sub>TM</sub>* is undecidable.

Is there a **theoretical way** to derive an object that maps to a given *valid* value? Yes: one could enumerate over all possible inputs (it is an infinite, but countable so enumerable), calculate the output and then validate it. Furthermore the evaluation of functions should happen in "parallel" since it is possible one of the function calls results in an infinite loop.

Nevertheless hoping that it is realistic to construct a *real* function that calculates the inverse is not advisable. In a practical sense the above sketched algorithm is **unfeasible**. It would require an enormous amount of memory to store all the simulations of these functions. Furthermore it is possible that these have side effects (like writing to a file). As a result you should make copies of everything that might have side effects. Furthermore in practice some side effects cannot be "virtualized" or "undone". If the function for instance communicates with a web server, you cannot "undo" the HTTP request. It can also take ages before a valid input structure is entered and evaluated.

Like [@JohnColeman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871976/how-to-revert-the-functionality-of-a-lambda-function-in-python/43872367?noredirect=1#comment74780352_43872367) says in his comment the fact that a function is not (feasibly) inverse is **sometimes desired behavior**. In asymmetrical encryption for instance the public key is usually publicly available. Nevertheless we do not want the message encrypted by the public key to be (efficiently) computable. A lot of todays cryptography and security depends on the fact that it is hard or impossible to perform the inverse operation of a function.

A final note is that of course it can be possible to construct an "inverse constructor" for *certain families* of functions. But in *general* (meaning a "inverse generator" that can take any kind of function as input), it is impossible.

Comment: @JohnColeman: yeah sorry, my mistake. Thanks for commenting :).

Comment: Another point is that public key cryptography is based on the fact that inverting computable functions, even when possible, is often much, much harder than computing the original function. Among other things -- a universal reverser would have to be an RSA cracker.

Comment: Another typical example of functions which is deliberately one-way are [hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). We rely on the fact that `hash(input) = output` is predictable and unitary (two inputs cannot yield the same hash), but going from `output` to `input` is not possible (= feasible with current technology)

Answer (score 1):

To regenerate your data, *you* need to invert the mappings that were applied to it. There is no general function-inverse operator in Python or any other programming language, for the reasons that @Willem explained, but humans are pretty good at identifying and reversing simple manipulations. With enough work, it is possible to understand and reverse complicated manipulations too. This is part of how hackers reverse-engineer programs and algorithms, and it is what you need to do too if your data is worth the effort. (Of course you can partially
 automate the process, especially if you know the *kinds* of manipulations that have been applied, e.g. if you wrote them yourself.)

If you have the source code, it's relatively easy: Inspect each function, write a suitable inverse (to the extent that hey exist), and write a main loop that somehow determines which inverse to apply. If you don't have the source code but have the compiled program (`.pyc` or `.pyo` files), you can still disassemble them and puzzle out what they do. See the `dis` module (but it's not at at all trivial):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(transformer)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (value)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (title)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

So... the bottom line is, you have to do it yourself. Good luck with it.

Comment: Well in my opinion I had the idea that the `transformer` can be anything, so it is "unknown" at "compile time" what it will be.

Comment: Theoretically a transformation could be anything, but I'd say the odds are about 99% that the OP processed their data, lost the original, and is now trying to recover it.